# Why I can't run the command "install NPM"

Tags: npm

I have a project with Vue.js on GitHub which is built by my colleague and I want to see it in the local. After I clone in VScode and I want to use `NPM install` to first install NPM, but I failed and I don't understand what is the problem. the error message is:

```
    ../ext/call.cc:104:53: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    Local<String> current_key(Nan::To<String>(keys->Get(i)).ToLocalChecked());
                                              ~~~~~~^~~
/Users/alexchen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/alexchen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../ext/call.cc:681:27: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    if (!op->ParseOp(obj->Get(type), &ops[i])) {
                     ~~~~~^~~
/Users/alexchen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/alexchen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
```

Here is my version of Node and NPM

```
node -v
v13.10.1
```

```
npm -v
6.13.7
```

Is it a compatibility issue?

Comment: Do you have a link to the project on github?

Comment: Most likely you are trying to install an npm package that needs an older version of node

Comment: Ask your friend what their node and npm version is

Comment: How can i return to an old version ?